# Convert GMT to IST (India Standard Time) using javascript?

Tags: javascript, date, timezone, utc, pst

I have a date format is GMT or UTC.

```
var mydate  = '2020-01-14T17:43:37.000Z'
```

I want to convert this date in IST format so according to this date the output I need in this format.

```
var date = '2020-Jan-15 12:45'
```

Comment: That starting date is neither PST nor PDT. It's GMT ( or UTC if you prefer).

Comment: Use momentjs with time zone, if time in UTC then just add the mins to timestamp

Answer (score 16):

You can specify an IANA time zone identifier in the options passed to `toLocaleString`.  The identifier for India is `Asia/Kolkata`.

```
var s = new Date('2020-01-14T17:43:37.000Z').toLocaleString(undefined, {timeZone: 'Asia/Kolkata'});
```

This will do the correct time zone conversion, as the input is in UTC (as specified by the `Z` at the end).

`undefined` means to use the user's locale for the formatting of the date and time.  This is usually what you want.  If you want a more particular format (like what you specified in your question), you can provide a specific locale string and/or adjust the other options for `toLocaleString`, as given [in the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString).

Also, note that the conversion in your question is incorrect.  India is 5 hours an 30 minutes offset from UTC.  Thus the correct output is `2020-01-14 23:13:37`  (in whatever format you like)

Comment: Minor quibble: [*IANA*](https://www.iana.org/time-zones) uses "representative locations" like Asia/Kolkata since not all places in the same timezone use the same historic or daylight saving offsets. ;-)

Comment: @RobG - debatable terminology, sure.  The [theory file](https://data.iana.org/time-zones/theory.html) in the tzdb calls them "identifiers" in a heading.  They are also called "entries" in the [tz-link file](https://data.iana.org/time-zones/tz-link.html).  I prefer "identifiers" because they uniquely identify a time zone, and are suitable for storing in an "ID" property in a class or field in a database, etc. :)

Comment: Sure, but it identifies a representative location that has a specific set of timezone offset rules and history for a place or administrative area within a timezone, it's not a timezone identifier *per se*. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Another option for you is to use the  [moment](https://momentjs.com/) and  [moment timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/) modules for timezone conversion, they are very flexible and you can format the resulting date object according to whichever format you wish.

As mentioned by @matt-johnson-pint (thank you!) you can also use the very cool [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/) library for this purpose, I've added an example below.

```js
const mydate  = "2020-01-14T17:43:37.000Z"

// Create a UTC date object. The moment constructor will recognize the date as UTC since it includes the 'Z' timezone specifier.
let utcDate = moment(mydate);

// Convert the UTC date into IST
let istDate = moment(mydate).tz("Asia/Kolkata");

console.log("Using Moment.js:");
console.log(`UTC date (iso): ${utcDate.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss")}`);
console.log(`IST date (iso): ${istDate.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss")}`);

const DateTime = luxon.DateTime;

utcDate = DateTime.fromISO(mydate);
istDate = DateTime.fromISO(mydate).setZone("Asia/Kolkata");

console.log(`\nUsing Luxon:`);
console.log(`UTC date (iso): ${utcDate.toFormat("yyyy-LL-dd HH:mm:ss")}`);
console.log(`IST date (iso): ${istDate.toFormat("yyyy-LL-dd HH:mm:ss")}`);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-timezone-with-data-1970-2030.js"></script>
<script src="https://moment.github.io/luxon/global/luxon.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: FYI, as a maintainer of Moment and Moment-Timezone - We recommend that you use [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/) for all new development.  Consider Moment in maintenance mode.  Thanks.  (Feel free to add a Luxon sample to your response.)

Comment: Thank you very much for the information. I'll move on up to using Luxon!