# How to convert Date and Time from GMT to IST in Node JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, date, timezone, converters

I have

```
str mydate = 'Tue, 08 Feb 2022 09:17:16 GMT '
```

and I want to convert it to IST in a fomat like this:

```
str date = 'Tue, 08 Feb 2022 12:18:16 IST'
```

How can I do that? in node js?

Comment: you can find the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59749564/convert-gmt-to-ist-india-standard-time-using-javascript).

Comment: @fixedDrill— just mark it as a duplicate. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var istDate = new Date('Tue, 08 Feb 2022 09:17:16 GMT').toLocaleString(undefined, {timeZone: 'Asia/Kolkata'});
```